# Grails save() passes although objects in hasMany relationship has constraint errors

Tags: grails, constraints, has-many, domain-object

What is the correct way to handle domain save errors on domain classes under the hasMany relationship? It seems that calling save() on the owning side of the relation will return true even if there are validation errors on the owned objects.

How should I test this in running code or integration test?

I have reduced my problem to the following simple case.

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [emails: Email]    
    static constraints = { }
}
```

.

```
class Email {
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    String emailAddress

    static constraints = {
        emailAddress unique: true
    }
}
```

Here are two suggestions on how to do this. Neither is really elegant.

First one calls save() individually to each on the hasMany relationship. What is good here is that we get the exact error out of the test case. This pretty cumbersome.

```
@Test
void testHasManyConstraintsOwned(){
 def john = new User(login: 'johnDoe')
 def email = new Email(emailAddress: 'john@gmail.com')
 def duplicateEmail = new Email(emailAddress: 'john@gmail.com')

 john.save() // otherwise: NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID" is thrown for email.save()
 john.addToEmails(email).addToEmails(duplicateEmail)

 assert email.save()
 assert !duplicateEmail.save()
 assert "unique"== duplicateEmail.errors.getFieldError("emailAddress").code
}
```

Another approach uses try/catch to detect the excepted fail. Problem here is that we have no way of knowing what went wrong and thus cannot actually test that the domain constraints are working as we expect.

```
@Test
void testHasManyConstraintsOwningExcp(){
    def john = new User(login: 'johnDoe')
    def email = new Email(emailAddress: 'john@gmail.com')
    def duplicateEmail = new Email(emailAddress: 'john@gmail.com')

    john.addToEmails(email).addToEmails(duplicateEmail)
    try {
        john.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        assert false // should not reach here
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

What is the correct way to test and to react in the application code?

Comment: I'm not sure if your failOnError will apply to related domain classes.

Comment: Sorry I hit the 5 min limit for edits on my previous comment :(

I'd prefer the first method, because you can precisely show the error that was produced. In the second example, when I need to know what happened and I got only an exception, I  to use the shouldFail method in my unit test, to test the exception, and check the message for some known substring: shouldFail(ExceptionType){....}.contains 'known substring' (or startsWith)